# Enlace dentro de variable string php

Tags: php, variables, enlace

Tengo intención de enviar un correo en php y para eso preparo la variable `$cuerpo` que necesito que contenga un enlace.
Como se ve abajo, he intentado hacer `echo '<a href="https://datoweb.com">Enlace</a>'` Pero no ha dado resultado.

```
 $cuerpo= "Para confirmar su registro, por favor pulse  en este". echo '<a href="https://datoweb.com">Enlace</a>';
        $para=$email;
        $de='[Registro Web]'.' Dni: ['.$_POST["dni"]. '] Nombre:  '. $_POST["nombre"] ;
        $headers = 'From: ' . "\r\n" .
         'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n" .
         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($para,$de,$cuerpo,$headers);
```

Usando el enlace del campañero Vera Canet he probado a mandar el correo como web y de esta forma me ha resultado, queda mucho mas bonito estéticamente.

```
$cuerpo = "Formulario de registro \n";
$cuerpo = '<html>'.
   '<head><title>Registro </title></head>'.
   '<body><h1>Bienvenid@ '.$nombre.'</h1>'.
   'Haga click en este  <a href="www.google.es"><b>Enlace</b></a> para 
    activar su cuenta de usuario en el privada'.
    '<hr>'.
    'Enviado por Grupo la Caña'.


 '</body>'.
    '</html>';

            $para=$email;
            $de='[Registro Web]'.' Dni: ['.$_POST["dni"]. '] Nombre:  '. 
           $_POST["nombre"] ;
            $headers ='Reply-To:correo@correo.es ' . "\r\n" .        
            $headers = 'From: correo@correo.es' . "\r\n" .
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
             mail($para,$de,$cuerpo,$headers);
```

Comment: Intenta eliminar el echo

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de una asignación de valor a una variable no puedes usar un **echo**, basta con concatenarlo. Por otro lado, si lo que necesitas es que el enlace sea eso, un enlace, en el correo que recibe el usuario, debes poner las cabeceras adecuadas, incluyendo el mime y el content type.

En mis comentarios tienes el enlace donde te explican esas dos cabeceras, que te expongo también aquí abajo modificando tu código y añadiendo las dos cabeceras

```
$cuerpo= "Para confirmar su registro, por favor pulse  en este <a href='https://datoweb.com'>Enlace</a>";
$para=$email;
$de='[Registro Web]'.' Dni: ['.$_POST["dni"]. '] Nombre:  '. $_POST["nombre"] ;
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
           'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n".
           'From: ' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($para,$de,$cuerpo,$headers);
```

Comment: Gracias, pero cuando abro el correo y veo la variable $cuerpo, veo esto: Para confirmar su registro, por favor pulse  en este <a href='https://datoweb.com'>Enlace</a> Yo lo que necesito es ver solo la palabra  Enlace y que al pinche direccione a  datoweb.com

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta no estaba redactada correctamente puesto que faltaba esta información. Dicho esto, revisa este enlace, tiene la clave para conseguir lo que quieres ;) http://lineadecodigo.com/php/enviar-email-con-formato-html-en-php/ Y ya como recomendación, en vez de usar la función nativa **mail** de php, yo optaría por usar alguna clase como phpMailer

Comment: Creo que no me he expresado bién, lo siento. No se si lo que necesito es que el correo sea en formato html o no, lo que  quiero es simplemente hacer un enlace. que la persona al pulsar en una palabra se dirija a una dirección web. Igual que al pulsar sobre mi nombre en esta pagina o el tuyo, te dirige a otro sitio.

Comment: Sí, pero para eso tienes que mandar el correo en formato html. Si mandas el correo en formato texto, el receptor recibe eso... texto plano, y los textos planos no llevan enlaces, ni podrían llevar css, ni tablas... nada, sólo texto. Por eso el correo debes enviarlo como html, para que te acepte etiquetas html como <a> <strong> y similares. Prueba con lo que te decía en en link anterior y añade las cabeceras necesarias y me cuentas.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta para añadir lo que te faltaba. Pruébalo a ver